ProfileId not getting updated through Apex, Record-Triggered-Flow
I am trying to provide an option to community partner user to switch between different pages using LWC component and basis on their selection , I need to update the profile of the user.(Note-I have different pages configured through page variations based on profile of logged in user)
The need for updating profile is - I have some common objects used across different pages and has different page layout based on profiles.
Here is what I have tried so far

Called apex through my LWC - Didnt worked as community user does not have "Manage User" permission, neither we can give it.
Future method - This is not feasible as it would have separate transaction and I wanted to update profile synchronously and refresh the page so that user sees pages based on selection & they will start seeing layouts based on profile they are switched to.
API call - This works, by calling an apex method which makes API call on behalf of admin user but API limit would come into the picture.

Now I am looking at trigger or record triggered flow approach (Before update) and I tried with below code in trigger which runs without any runtime error but does not actually update the profile.
public override void onBeforeUpdateFunction(){
        // Calling helper method to get a map of "<ProfileName, ProfileId>"
        Map<String,String> mapPortalNameToProfileId = getProfileId();
        for(Sobject obj : Trigger.new){
            User newRecord = (User)obj;
            User oldRecord = (User)Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.Id);
                if(mapPortalNameToProfileId.containsKey(newRecord.newProfileName__c)){
                    newRecord.ProfileId = mapPortalNameToProfileId.get(newRecord.PC_DefaultPortal__c);
                }
        }

Does anyone know why its not updating it? Any idea if salesforce silently ignores profile update through apex?

You'd need a debug log to check in detail why "runs without any runtime error but does not actually update the profile".
I don't think any amount of @future, queueable, schedulable, flow, scheduled flow... is going to save you because ultimately they will all still run on the rights of the user that submitted the job. You could verify by debuggingUserInfo.getUserId(), getUserName() etc (or in flow similar "dollar variables")
One trick would be to

create a Platform Event for this.
raise a Platform Event requesting the profile change
write a trigger that handles the event
(and this is the magic bit) use a special metadata file to modify how the events are handled

You can't edit #4 in Setup UI, you need to hand-craft and deploy a special file: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm
You'd make the event's trigger handler run as an internal user, ideally Sysadmin that has the "Manage Users".
And then... back to your aura/lwc/whatever, something that fires the event and then waits couple seconds "is it done yet"? Queries the user's profile and when it flips - redirect the user.
